# C++: Store pointer to a member function of an object in another object

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, member-functions

I have a class which shall invoke a function specified by the user on certain occasions. Therefore the class has a method `void setExternalPostPaintFunction(void(*function)(QPainter&));` that can be used to "register" a function. This function then will be called on that occasion:

```cpp
class A {
    public:
        void setExternalPostPaintFunction(void(*function)(QPainter&));
    private:
        void (*_externalPostPaint)(QPainter&);
        bool _externalPostPaintFunctionAssigned;
};
```

The function pointer is saved in the member variable `_externalPostPaint`. The implementation of `setExternalPostPaintFunction` looks like this:

```cpp
void A::setExternalPostPaintFunction(void(*function)(QPainter&)) {
    _externalPostPaint = function;
    _externalPostPaintFunctionAssigned = true;
}
```

Now, this works with normal functions. However, I want to be able to also pass pointers to **member functions** of objects. From what I know I also have to pass and store the pointer to the object in this case. However, I don't know which type the other object will have. So I guess I'm forced to use templates. I already thought of something like this:

```cpp
class A {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void setExternalPostPaintFunction(void(T::*function)(QPainter&), T* object);
    private:
        void (T::*_externalPostPaint)(QPainter&);       //<- This can't work!
        bool _externalPostPaintFunctionAssigned;
};
```

This way I can pass a function pointer and an object pointer to `setExternalPostPaintFunction` and would probably be able to call the function on the object inside that function. But I'm not able to store it in the variable `_externalPostPaint` because the type `T` is only deduced when the function `setExternalPostPaintFunction` is called, thus I can't have a member variable that depends on this type, since the type of my member variable has to be known when the object is created and apart from that it cannot change, but it would have to in the case when a new function is assigned which possibly could be a member function of an object of different type.

So what is the proper way to do this, or is there any? I'm not super fit with templates and function pointers, so I might have overlooked something.

Anoter option would certainly be to create a functor class with a virtual member function which can be overwritten in a derived class and then pass + store an object pointer of that type instead of the function pointer. But I somehow would prefer my approach if it is somehow possible.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

TartanLlama brought me on the right track by suggesting the use of `std::function`. Here is how I solved it:

```cpp
class A {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void setExternalPostPaintFunction(T* object, void(T::*function)(QPainter&)) {
            _externalPostPaint = std::bind(function, object, std::placeholders::_1);
            _externalPostPaintFunctionAssigned = true;
        }
        void setExternalPostPaintFunction(std::function<void(QPainter&)> const& function);
    private:
        std::function<void(QPainter&)> _externalPostPaint;
        bool _externalPostPaintFunctionAssigned;
};
```

As you see, the pointer to the function/member function is stored in an `std::function<void(QPainter&)>` object now. The advantage is, that an `std::function` can basically store any callable target. Then there are two overloads: one that can be used for any `std::function` object that also accepts e.g. a normal function pointer (because the `std::function` that is expected then is implicitly constructed from that) and one for member functions that have to be called on an object (more for convenience). The latter is implemented as a template. This uses `std::bind` to create a `std::function` object of the call of that member function (the user passed) on the object (the user passed).

The overload that takes an `std::function` is implemented in the source file like this:

```cpp
void ImageView::setExternalPostPaintFunction(std::function<void(QPainter&)> const& function) {
    _externalPostPaint = function;
    _externalPostPaintFunctionAssigned = true;
}
```

Invoking that stored function in the code of class `A` is now as simple as that:

```cpp
//canvas is a QPainter instance    
if (_externalPostPaintFunctionAssigned) _externalPostPaint(canvas);
```

The user who wants to register a member function as callback function just has to do the following:

```cpp
//_imageView is an instance of "A"
//"MainInterface" is the type of "this"
_imageView->setExternalPostPaintFunction(this, &MainInterface::infoPaintFunction);
```

Or if it's not a member function but just a normal function:

```cpp
void someFunction(QPainter& painter) {
    //do stuff
}

_imageView->setExternalPostPaintFunction(&someFunction);
```

Or he can explicitly create a `std::function` object and pass it:

```cpp
std::function<void(QPainter&)> function = [&](QPainter& painter){ this->infoPaintFunction(painter); };
_imageView->setExternalPostPaintFunction(function);
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Is C++11 okay? `std::function` is perfect for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, C++ 11 is okay. I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::function`:

```
class A {
    public:
        //PostPaintFun can be anything which acts as a function taking a QPainter&
        //Could be a lambda, function pointer, functor, etc.
        using PostPaintFun = std::function<void(QPainter&)>;
        void setExternalPostPaintFunction(PostPaintFun fun);
    private:
        //Names beginning with an underscore are reserved, don't use them
        //Ending with an underscore is fine
        PostPaintFun fun_;
        bool externalPostPaintFunctionAssigned_;
};
```

Now you can use member functions like so:

```
struct B
{
    void exec(QPainter&) const;
};

void foo() {
    B b;
    a.setExternalPostPaintFunction(
        [b] (QPainter& p) {b.exec(p);}
    );
}

//or inside B
void B::foo() {
    a.setExternalPostPaintFunction(
        [this] (QPainter&p) {this->exec(p);}
    );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to ´std::function´. Your solution using a lambda is very elegant. However, I solved it slightly different, because I think it's somewhat easier for the user of the class. My way he doesn't have to create that lambda by himself but can just pass a pointer to his object and a pointer to the member function and my function `setExternalPostPaintFunction` does the rest using `std::bind`. I edited my question and added my solution. Maybe you could have a look at it and tell me what you think of it.

Comment: Cool, that's a fairly decent solution, but prevents users from passing in lambdas or functors. I'd suggest having one constructor which takes a `std::function` then one which takes a pointer to member function and an instance pointer for convenience.

Comment: Ok, already thought of that. Think I'll add another overload that directly takes an `std::function`.

Comment: Ah ok, I just realized that I now can take away that second overload I added (for function pointers) because `void setExternalPostPaintFunction(std::function<void(QPainter&)> const& function);` will also except a function pointer, that via the constructor of `std::function` is implicitly converted to a `std::function` object. Just one more question: Why do you do that `using PostPaintFun = std::function<void(QPainter&)>;`?

Comment: Just so I don't have to type it twice. DRY principle.

Comment: What's the difference to a `typedef`?

Comment: None in this case, but alias declarations can be templates, so I use them everywhere for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I prefer TartanLlama's answer, but here you have something it could work for you.

This might to need some work, but I'm sure you'll get the idea.

```
struct IFunctionHolder {};                      // Used for pointing to any FunctionHolder
typedef IFunctionHolder* functionHolder_ptr;    // Alias for IFunctionHolder* .

template<typename Function>                     // The template for the actual function holders.
struct FunctionHolder:  public IFunctionHolder
{
    Function function;
};


class A {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void setExternalPostPaintFunction(void(T::*function)(QPainter&), T* object);
    private:
        functionHolder_ptr *function_holder;            // This memeber can hold eny instantiation of template<> FunctionHolder.
                                                        // Instantiate this member wen calling setExternalPostPaintFunction
        bool _externalPostPaintFunctionAssigned;
};
```

You could have some code like this:

```
A some_a;
void some_a.setExternalPostPaintFunction(&SomeInstance::some_fnunction);    // Here take place the instantiation of FunctionHolder.
some_a.function_holder.function(some_painter);
```

Comment: I decided to go with the `std::function` approach. I added my solution to the question.