# Is it possible to define an anonymous member function in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, member-functions

I have a fun use case for my little pet project where I would like to have a

```
static map<std::string, pointer-to-member-function>
```

in a class. This is easy, if a bit cumbersome syntax, and it works beautifully.

What I would like to do also is to have the pointer-to-member-function be a simple lambda-expression in my static initializer. This would make it sooo easy to package things like this in a nice macro.

I want the pointer-to-member-function to have access to private class members, hence I cannot really use a normal lambda with "this" as a parameter.
However I cannot seem to find any way to define an anonymous member function -- c++ lambdas all seem to be free global functions?

Comment: Do you want `std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const C&)>>` ?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You can pass an instance of your class as parameter though.

Comment: If you capture the `this` pointer in a lambda it will behave much like a member function.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I should have been clearer in that I want the method to be able to access private members. Editing.

Comment: *"What I would like to do also is to have the pointer-to-member-function be a simple lambda-expression in my static initializer"* Can you show us an example? If it's something like `[](MyClass* self) { self->member_function(); }`, then you can use a `map<string, void(*)()>`, since lambdas (which are objects of class type) can be converted to a function pointer (iff they don't capture anything).

Comment: If you define the lambda in a member function it  "may access the same names that the member function itself may access."

Comment: You can use `std::bind` to bind a member function to an object instance. The resulting `std::function` object can then be executed like a normal function pointer. Maybe this question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30868884/1488118

Comment: @user1488118 `std::bind` does not return a `std::function` object. The name of its return type is not specified; the specification only guarantees certain properties of this type. `std::function<X>` is a wrapper type which can store any *function object* that can be invoked in a certain way (defined by `X`). So you *can* combine `bind` and `function`, but they're otherwise independent tools.

Comment: Can you show, in some kind of pseudo code, how you want a solution to look like? I have some ideas, but am unsure whether I understand your requirement correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `std::function<void(const MyClass&)>` in your map then you can store a lambda that takes an instance of your class as a parameter. As long as the lambda is defined in a member function of `MyClass` it will be able to access private class members of `MyClass`:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>

class MyClass {
private:
  void myPrivate() const { }
public:
  static std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const MyClass&)>> funcs;

  static void initFuncs() {
    funcs["test"] = [](const MyClass& mc) { mc.myPrivate(); };
  }
};

std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const MyClass&)>> MyClass::funcs;

int main() {
  MyClass::initFuncs();
  MyClass mc;
  MyClass::funcs["test"](mc);    
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RWjtxUYOiPssENIR).

Comment: Ah, so the lambda defined inside the class implicitly becomes a "friend"-like function. Cool. This will do what I want, and much easier types then pointer-to-member-functions. I have something to work with now!